Two different definitions of the Smirnov class
I have found two different definitions for the Smirnov class $\mathcal{N}^+$ on the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$. One is $\{f/g : f,g \text{ are bounded analytic functions and } g \text{ is an outer function } \}$  and the other is $\{f/g : f,g \text{ are bounded functions in the Hardy-space } H^2(\mathbb{D}) \text{ and } g \text{ is an outer function } \}$. I am confused, are these definitions the same?

What is the function $h$?

bounded analytic functions on the unit disc are automatically in $H^2$ so of course definitions are the same

but why does the other way work? $H^2$ functions are not bounded in general

not sure what you mean as you claim ${f/g : f,g \text{ are bounded functions in the Hardy-space } H^2(\mathbb{D}) \text{ and } g \text{ is an outer function } }$ which says bounded (and again all bounded analytic functions are in $H^2$)
